# NOT instanceof: object NOT belonging to a class

Tags: php

I saw that "instanceof" does not accept negation with the exclamation point ("!instanceof").
To check if an object does not belong to a class, what is the best way to get the same result as the following NOT valid code?

```
class foo {
   // properties and methods
}

if ($abc !instanceof foo) {
     $abc = new foo;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
if (!($abc instanceof foo)) {
     $abc = new foo;
}
```

For testing: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06bf0fa95326c2ea7f887bffa49c72d3fa1f211c